# jQuery colorbox gallery mix image and video

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Im using colorbox plugin and i wanna include some videos on gallery see this code: http://jsfiddle.net/29Bb4/ basicly video not loading when next item loads any idea?

when i use like this:

`$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});` it breaks gallery effect:

- or is there any good popup plugin that i can use both images and videos ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Since in your question you are allowing for alternate solutions/plugins**, I'd suggest you use fancybox.  Here is a demo of your example html.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Skpyw/3/

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

```
<p><a class="group1" rel="group1" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
        <p><a class="group1" rel="group1" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
        <p><a class="group1" rel="group1" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>

        <p><a class='group1 fancybox.iframe' rel="group1" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KHy7DGLTt8g?rel=0" title="video">Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a></p>


$(".group1").fancybox({
       maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight    : 600,
        fitToView    : false,
        width        : '70%',
        height        : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick    : false,
        openEffect    : 'none',
        closeEffect    : 'none' 
});

$('#btnOpen').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    $('.fancybox:eq(0)').click();
});
```

Comment: I love getting downvotes for answering a question.  The OP indicated other solutions were acceptable.

Answer (score 13):

Well you have different settings for your two content types (images and iframes).  It's easy to display them as the same group, but you have to define their settings separately:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
$(".iframe").colorbox({rel:'group1', iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

Comment: How can I get same result, but call Colorbox like this: `$.colorbox({...})`?